# How to enroll Google Authenticator by using Resource Owner Password Endpoint of Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0, google-authenticator

I'm using **Auth0** to authenticate users. I'm also using **Resource Owner Password Endpoint (/oauth/token)** to log the user in my SPA and enabled Google Authenticator to verify the authentication.

When a user enters their credentials into my login form, the token endpoint response an error that **MFA is required**. So in this document https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?javascript#resource-owner-password-and-mfa, I need to send a request to verify OTP code of user from Google Authenticator App.

But the problem is those users are not enrolled to use Google Authenticator before. 
**How can I get QR Code and show it to allow users enroll?**